# Prevent flip fluids simulation from generating random flying particles

Tags: particles, fluid-simulation

I feel a little bit stuck on my personal project and thought that it might be helpful to ask for help here.
The thing is, I desire to make flip fluids sim flowing out of skulls eyes straight down(similar to how any liquid falls down in real life), but I just can not figure out how to force it to fall down, for some reason simulation is random and liquid is just flying out of skull's eyes instead of flowing down(check pick)...is it because of scale/world settings or must I work with force fields? Any advise?
I will attach blend file just in case anybody feels like educating me.
Thanks in advance <3[image: bad fluid test]
[link to blender file download](https://www.mediafire.com/file/9d27fxivdoma13g/flips_test_skull.blend/file)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you select your domain object and checkout the physics properties under "enable surface tension" you will find:

[image]

If you hover your cursor over the question mark you will get:

[image]

so it should be clear what to do:

either uncheck surface tension...or decrease tension...or increase number of allowed max frame substeps.

Comment: I am blind. Thank you for healing my eyesight, kind man)